# Cordova / Phonegap -- jquery not executing Javascript on <div> load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

I have a single page (index.html) document for phonegap that displays different "pages" when each new "div" is referenced.  For example:

```
<div class="upage ui-page-theme-a" id="view_history" data-role="page" >
```

I am wanting to have a javascript function automatically execute via Jquery when the "div" is displayed.  My code is below.

However I can't get anything to cause it to execute on div load.  I can put an "onclick" call in the HTML, ie:

```
<a onclick="listMeasurements()" class="button" style="" data-role="button">List 
Current Measurements</a>
```

and that works fine, but for some reason I can't get it to execute just from loading.  Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Sorry in advance if I'm overlooking something obvious.

```
$('#view_history').on('pagecontainershow', listMeasurements()) ;

// I've also tried  bind() etc.



function listMeasurements() {
"use strict" ;
var fName = "listMeasurements():" ;

var measurements_recorded = window.localStorage.length;


$("#Measurements").html("<strong>" + measurements_recorded + "</strong> 
measurement(s) recorded");

// Empty the list of recorded tracks
$("#measurement_list").empty();

// Iterate over all of the recorded tracks, populating the list
       for(var i=0; i<measurements_recorded; i++){

 $("#measurement_list").append("<li data-uib=\"jquery_mobile/listitem\" data-ver=\"0\"><span><a href=\"#results-graphs\" data-ajax=\"false\">" + window.localStorage.key(i) + "</a></span></li>");

                  }

        $('#measurement_list').listview().listview('refresh'); 
   }
```

Comment: Where are you firing this 'pagecontainershow' event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From jQuery Mobile 1.4.2 the events have changed & don't work with a binding to a specific page like you have done i.e this -

```
$('#view_history').on('pagecontainershow', listMeasurements()) ;
```

won't work anymore.

You need to put a binding something like this on document -

```
function showSomeLove() {
  alert("What is love, baby don't hurt me, no more!");
}

$(document).on( "pagecontainershow", function( event, ui ) {
   var currentPageId = $( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer( "getActivePage" ).attr('id');
   if(currentPageId == 'page-a') {  
     /*Execute or Call your function here*/
      showSomeLove();
   } else if(currentPageId == 'page-b') {
      /*do something else*/
   }
});
```

**Here's a WORKING DEMO** - http://codepen.io/nitishdhar/pen/gnqFH

For more details read the pagecontainer widget - http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/

Comment: Thanks!  That worked!  I'm guessing it's ok to not have specific references (ie:  "#targetpage" to the div areas (if we have different events for  different divs) as long as the function only alters/affects content of the node in the div?  But I should be able to read the Jquery info on that -- Thanks again!

Comment: You can have one pagecontainershow event and inside that you can read whats the active page and based on that perform a different action. Jqm lets you read active page id

Comment: @user3662262 - I have updated the answer to show how you can read the current page & then perform some action based on that.

Comment: Thanks again!  I'll read through your latest post as well, this was very helpful!